# How to use ajax in dropdown to select items, when I am working with the django framework?

Tags: ajax, django

I am working on a Django framework and I am very much new to both Django and Ajax. I have used a drop down list and I need to select an item from that and accordingly display its details in a table like format. Can someone help me with an Ajax code for this. Also, it would be great if you could suggest how should I build the corresponding view for it.

The code that I tried to write is something like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#profession').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/fdp/instance_creation/(\d+)',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        // This is query string i.e. country_id=123
        data: {instance_id : $('#profession').val()},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == null || data ==""){
            }
            else{
            document.getElementById("mytablebody").innerHTML="";
            var srno=1;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var table = document.getElementsByName("tablebody")[0];
                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                var cell1 = document.createElement('td');
                var cell2 = document.createElement('td');
                var cell3 = document.createElement('td');
                var cell4 = document.createElement('td');
               // var cell5 = document.createElement('td');
                var text1 = document.createTextNode({{forloop.counter}});
                var text2 = document.createTextNode(data[i].{{workshopid}});
                var text3 = document.createTextNode(data[i].{{startdate}});
                var text4 = document.createTextNode(data[i].{{enddate}});
               // var text5 = document.createTextNode("");


                cell1.appendChild(text1);
                cell2.appendChild(text2);
                cell3.appendChild(text3);
                cell4.appendChild(text4);
                //cell5.appendChild(text5);

                row.appendChild(cell1);
                row.appendChild(cell2);
                row.appendChild(cell3);
                row.appendChild(cell4);
                //row.appendChild(cell5);

                table.appendChild(row);
                srno++;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

I am completely new in this field so it would be nice if you could pardon me for small mistakes.

Comment: in your ajax url, is `/fdp/instance_creation/(\d+)` the same regular expression in your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen with this URL?

```
url: '/fdp/instance_creation/(\d+)',
```

Do you want something to be substituted at the end?  You will have to do that beforehand.  Do you want this:

```
url: '/fdp/instance_creation/' + $('#profession').val(),
```

Also, what did you mean by this code:

```
var text1 = document.createTextNode({{forloop.counter}});
var text2 = document.createTextNode(data[i].{{workshopid}});
var text3 = document.createTextNode(data[i].{{startdate}});
var text4 = document.createTextNode(data[i].{{enddate}});
```

The `{{}}` would be filled in on the Django side as templates.  It really feels like you'd at least want:

```
var text1 = document.createTextNode(i);
```

The other ones could work if they resolve to field names in the JSON.

As for a view, you just need to respond with JSON data. To test, just make a view function that returns a hard-coded string like `"[{'fld': 'val', 'fld2': 'val2'}]"` (I don't know your real field names, but fill them in correctly)